# Парсинг Betfair

Tags: php, curl, парсер, phpquery

Всем привет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такие ошибки появляются, если парсить сайт **www.betfair.com** этим скриптом:

```
<?php
require_once "phpQuery.php";
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.betfair.com/');
phpQuery::newDocument($html);
$text = pq('body');
echo $text;
phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
?>
```

**[Скачать библиотеку phpQuery](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/phpquery/phpQuery-0.9.5.386-onefile.zip)**

---

Возможно, ошибка возникает из-за того, что на сайте используется протокол HTTPS, поэтому попробуем использовать cURL:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.betfair.com');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

В итоге выдает пустую страницу.
Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с данной проблемой?

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);` FALSE на TRUE

Comment: @mix, по-прежнему пустая страница

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой вариант работает, проверил

```
<?php 
    // print_r($client_secret); die();
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.betfair.com');
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
    $result = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
```

Comment: у меня другие сайты парсит, а вместо этого опять пустая страница

Comment: Тогда надо заголовки посмотреть, что сервер отдает.